# Create a Batch HTTP API With multipart response

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, multipart

Actually, I´ve create a Batch HTTP API that receives a JSON array with many different requests to our backend server. The Batch API just call all of these requests to a load balancer, wait for the return of all of them and return a new JSON to the client.

The client receives a huge JSON array response with its indices in the same position as the request, so it is easy to know what response is addressed for what request.

The motivation for this API was to solve the 5 browser simultaneous connections and improve performance as the Batch API has a much more direct access to the server (we do not have a reverse proxy or a SSL server between then).

The service is running pretty well, but now I have some new requirements as it is gaining more use. First, the service can use a lot of memory as it has a buffer for each request that will only be flushed when all responses are ready (I am using an ordered JSON Array). More, since it can take some time to all requests be delivered, the client will need to wait everything be processed before receiving a single byte.

I am planning change the service to return each response as soon it is available (and solve both issues above). And would like to share and validate my ideas with you:

1. I will change the response from a JSON response to a multipart response.
2. The server will include, for every part, the index of the response
3. The server will flush the response once its available
4. The client XHR will need to understand multipart content type response and be able to process each part as soon as it is available.

I will create a PoC to validate every step, but at this moment I would like to validate the idea and hear some thoughts about it. Here some doubts I have about the solution:

1. From what I read, I am in doubbt of that content-type is right for the response. multipart/mixed? multipart/digest?
2. Can I use an accept request header to identify if the client is able to handle the new service implementation? If so, what is the right accept header for this? My plan is to use the same endpoint but very accept header.
3. How can I develop a XHR client that is able to process many parts of a single response as soon as they are available? I found some ideias on the Web but I am not entirely confident with then.

Comment: Sounds like you are very fixated on your design. If not, you might consider using [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) to stream the data. That is, unless you intend on writing a custom browser to accommodate a custom response type.

Comment: No, I am not. I mean, thats why I am here trying to figure out if this is the best solution. I will take a look on WebRTC, but it seems too new for my needs (considering it has not a stable specification at this moment). That´s something I missed on the question above: this service must run in a closed SaaS platform with clients having different browsers (like IE11) and firewalls (some of then even _open_ SSL connections and blocks websockets, for example).

Comment: youch..Sounds like quite a challenge. But a fun one to solve. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I will change the response from a JSON response to a multipart
>      response.
> 2. The server will include, for every part, the index of the
>      response
> 3. The server will flush the response once its available
> 4. The
>      client XHR will need to understand multipart content type response and
>      be able to process each part as soon as it is available.

The XHR protocol will not support this work flow through a single request from the client. Since XHR relies heavily on the HTTP protocol for communications, XHR follows the HTTP connection rules. The first and most important rule: HTTP connections are always initiated by the client. Another rule: XHR returns the entire content-body or fails.

The implications for your workflow is that each part of the multipart response must be requested individually by the client.

> 1. From what I read, I am in doubbt of that content-type is right for the
>      response. multipart/mixed? multipart/digest?

You should be in doubt as there is no provision in the specfication to do this. The response-type attribute is limited to [the empty string (default), "arraybuffer", "blob", "document", "json", and "text".](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responsetype-attribute) it is possible to set the override MIME type header, but that does not change the response type. Event given that case, the XHR spec is very clear about what it will send back. It is one of the types listed above [as documented here.](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-response-attribute)

> 2. Can I use an accept
>      request header to identify if the client is able to handle the new
>      service implementation? If so, what is the right accept header for
>      this? My plan is to use the same endpoint but very accept header.

Custom HTTP headers are designed to assist us in telling the server what our capabilities are on the client. This is easily done. it doesn't necessarily have to be in the `accept` header (as that also is a defined list of MIME types).

> 3. How
>      can I develop a XHR client that is able to process many parts of a
>      single response as soon as they are available? I found some ideias on
>      the Web but I am not entirely confident with then.

XHR is processed natively by the client and cannot be overridden for all sorts of security reasons. So this is unlikely to be available as a solution for this reason.

Note: ordinarily one might suggest the use of a custom version of Chromium, but your constraints do not allow for that.